# Bamidbar: What makes Shimon different?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, number, words, shevatim-12-tribes, bamidbar-parsha

During krias haTorah, I noticed that while during the counting, most tribes were counted like this (taking Yehuda as an example):

> לבני יהודה תולדתם למשפחתם לבית אבותם במספר שמות מבן עשרים שנה ומעלה כל יצא צבא
>   
> [Bamidar 1:26](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9929#v=26)

On the other hand, Shimon gets a different treatment from every other tribe:

> לבני שמעון תולדותם למשפחתם לבית אבתם **פקדיו** במספר שמות **לגלגלתם כל זכר** מבן עשרים שנה ומעלה כל יצא צבא
>   
> [ibid. 1:22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9929#v=22)

Can anyone explain why that is?

[sourced answers preferred]

Comment: The answer can be seen here.Lekach Tov,Medrash Agadah and ,Medrash Hagadol. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_51470_30.pdf

Comment: naphtali the last tribe is also different. The lamed of livnai is missing. Either because they were the only ones left or they had more girls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This source](http://shlomokluger.com/Other-Books/Rashi-Terumas-Hadeshen/Bamidbar.html#2) (found thanks to a link in the comments;) discusses my question (and others), and answers (quoting Terumas Hadeshen explaining Rashi) that because Shimon was not the leader of his דגל flag-group, he got the word "פקודיו" added to his count as compensation.
[He adds that Menashe also has a change in his count -- "והחונים עליו," for a similar reason (his younger brother אפרים was head of his group)]

---

[This source](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_51470_30.pdf) (Thanks to @[sam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1418/sam)) brings down several comments that discuss this question, and here they are:

- לקח טוב writes that Shimon was counted with the word פקודיו because they would eventually lose a whole bunch of people.
- מדרש אגדה writes that Shimon and Reuven were counted differently because they annoyed their father (Yaakov; I would assume with שכם and with switching the beds), and needed to atone for that.
- Similarly, מדרש הגדול writes that the word פקודיו was used for Shimon in the sense of פוקד עון אבות, that the sins of the ancestor (Shimon) are remembered [again, probably שכם].